# Center a UIView with auto layout is just not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have `UIImageView` which is in the screen size (`auto layouts` are 0 to all neighbours) .
Inside it, i have another `UIImageView.` , i would like it to always be in the Center of its parent `imageview`(hence on the Center of the screen) , and so it will change its size in relation to screen size, and keep aspect ratio .

So inside the `storyboard`(Xcode 6), i am trying to control drag from the Center view to its parent, than i add `aspect ratio constrain` ,than i see its aspect ratio,and that the constrain added.

Running this now, will **NOT**  change image size and it stay in the same size for all screens.

Than in the same way , i want to Center it , so i control drag to its superview , than chose `Center X` and `Center Y` , needless to say that its **not** centred to any screen size.

Why is it has to be so hard to place a view in the Center ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's super easy. See my images:

[image]

Then you need width/height-constraints:

[image]

And you're done!

To replace your view in storyboard according to constraints, just select the view itself and use update frames:

[image]

Edit:

If you want aspect-ratio width/height, just do this (The multiplier part):
[image]

---

---

---

EDIT 2:

Clarification of how to open the first window. Then just press the checkboxes to add the constraints:

[image]

These "center in container"-constraints should be the same as the added ones in this window (CTRL-drag to superview to open this):
[image]

EDIT 3:

To clarify what button to press:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but, things are not like that in reality . first, your first image shows a window, which has horizontal centre in container, and i dont have these options, my window looks like your window in the second view (how did you open the window in the first view? ) , second thing, you said "just set the width and height" , but to which value ?  all my views has to change their size according to screen, so what value do you chose in the width and height ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not having the options. They should be there if your view-hierarchy is correct. Secondly; see my edit for the aspect ratio-constraints. (They are new for xcode6, so they wont be there in xcode5)

Comment: In Xcode 6 you dont have that window that you show in your first photo. you just dont have this window. How did you open that window that called " add new alignments to constrains"  ?

Comment: Yes you do. See my edit again, the last picture. Select the view that you want to add constraints too, and just press that button

Comment: Also added a second image to show that it's the same thing as ctrl-dragging to superview

Comment: thanks very much for your effort, i will accept your answer, although its really not clear. you say "Then just press the checkboxes to add the constraints:"  , again , when i chose a UIImageView, **HOW** i open a window that called "add new alignment to constrains" ???

Comment: See my second last image! There's a damn button in the bottom right, i.e where the popover is anchored! Added a third image with some red arrows for you sir.

Comment: Also, you know what a "Checkbox" is right? The small squares to the left of the last image (The image with three huge red arrows). There's two (2) checkboxes to the left. :) I'm not angry ^^

Comment: Oh yea, i know what a check box is, but to be honest i wanted to deeply understand how it works, saying: "just set the width" is not helpful for me, how do you chose a width anyway if it has to be changed ..

Comment: Even if you have a constraint with a "fixed width", you can make an IBOutlet to the constraint and change its constant at run-time, and the view will resize itself.

Comment: where are the images you make reference to?