# Setting gradient background color to LaunchScreen which will display a logo image at center

Tags: ios, uiimageview, splash-screen, launch-screen

I have a requirement to set a Gradient background to the launch screen with a `UIImageView` in the center which shows the app logo . I tried having a view controller but I realised code will never be invoked.

I need some way to get behaviour as the code below does

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
```

I went through lot of answers about the same topic,  most of the questions on gradient colour don't seem to have any  additional requirements like showing another image other than the background .

I can hardcode the color in IB but i don't get the gradient.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot run code or use any custom classes in the Launch Screen. Basically the launch screen can use an interface builder file and accommodate size classes / auto layout, but you cannot create a gradient in code like you have.

You'll have to supply a stretchable image, which contains enough data for it to be viable in all resolutions.

Comment: Thanks wottle, I have  another image to be shown at center , that's where I am stuck :-(

Comment: You can do that with autolayout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866752/3708242  Are you using a launch screen storyboard?

Comment: Yes , I am using story board

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work It just requires a bit more work and a slightly larger app to store the gradient images. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 layers of `UIImageView`:

The first is large and contain the background gradient image, and a second layer of centered image (with transparent backgrount) of the logo.